# `apply` doesn't work for function as object's property

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, apply

According to [JavaScript Patterns book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) (p. 79), this should work:

```
 var ob = {
    fn: function foo(m) {alert(m);}
 };
 fn.apply(ob,['m']);
```

It doesn't work.

`fn is not defined` error thrown.

These 2 work OK:

```
ob.fn.apply(ob,['m']);
```

and

```
ob.fn.apply(null,['m']);
```

Why doesn't just `fn.apply(ob,['m'])` work? Can't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fn` doesn't work because it's not a variable in scope. If `window.fn` was defined, or `var fn` was defined elsewhere, then you'd be able to access it as `fn.apply`. Because neither of those are defined, you need to use the full path to the function on the object:

```
ob.fn.apply(...);
```

If you *want* fn to be defined, you could simply set it:

```
var ob,
    fn;

ob = {
  fn:function(){...}
};
fn = ob.fn;

fn.apply(ob, ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

`fn` isn't defined in the global scope. It's a member of `ob`. If that came from a book it's a typo.